# Why does my raspberry pi reboot instead of power down?

Tags: power, web-server

I'm having some issues powering down the Raspberry Pi through a web interface.

I have a Tornado server which basically serves a button, and upon clicking it executes the following command:

```
subprocess.os.system('sudo shutdown -h now')
```

Upon clicking the button, the Pi powers down, then I have a blank screen with a cursor blinking, and after a few seconds, it powers back up.

The strange thing is that if I just open a Python3 terminal and issue the same command, it properly powers down.

I'm powering the Pi from a USB charger.

*Any idea why I get this different behaviour?*

**Additional info**

The server is run as a systemd process

```
[Unit]
Description=Serve a configuration website
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/pi_server.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

pi_server.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import wifi
import subprocess

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def _create_form(self):
        html = '''
            <form method='post'>
                <button name='restart' value='restart'>Restart</button>
            </form>
            <form method='post'>
                <button name='restart' value='poweoff'>Poweroff</button>
            </form>
        '''
        return html 

    def get(self):
        self.write(self._create_form())

    def post(self):
        print('clicked?')
        for key in self.request.arguments:
            if 'restart' in key:
                subprocess.os.system('sudo shutdown -r now')
            elif 'poweroff' in key:
                subprocess.os.system('sudo shutdown -h now')
        self.write(self._create_form())

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8000, address='0.0.0.0')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
import os
import subprocess
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815672/python-cgi-script-basic-html-form-with-two-submit-buttons).

Basically, you need to give your buttons different names, not different values.
If you look at your if statement, the first condition is 'restart', and both your buttons are named 'restart'.